# Tagging and Training NER dataset

Tags: tags, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I have a data set and I want to tag it for Named Entity Recognition. My dataset is in Persian.
I want to know how should I tag expressions like :

*** آقای مهدی کاظمی  = Mr Mehdi Kazemi / Mr will Smith. >>> (names with titles) should I tag all as a person or just the first name and last name should be tagged? (I mean should i also tag "Mr")

Mr  >>  b_per     ||     Mr >> O

Mehdi  >>   i_per || Mehdi >> b_per

Kazemi  >> i_per || Kazemi >> i_per

*** بیمارستان نور = Noor hospital >>> Should I tag the name only or the name and hospital both as Named Entity?

*** Eiffel tower / The Ministry of Defense (I mean the us DOD for example) >>> in Persian it is called :
وزارت دفاع    (vezarate defa)
should I only tag Defense ? or all together?

There are many more examples for schools, movies, cities, countries and.... since we use the entity class before the named entity.

I would appreciate if you can help me with tagging this dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you some examples from the CoNLL 2003 training data:

"Mr." is not tagged as part of the person, so titles are ignored.

"Columbia Presbyterian Hospital" is tagged as (LOC, LOC, LOC)

"a New York hospital" (O, LOC, LOC, O)

"Ministry of Commerce" is (ORG, ORG, ORG)

I think "Eiffel Tower" should be (LOC, LOC)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you tag as the way you want the output to look. It's up to you if you want titles included, for example. However, Core NLP won't tag overlapping entities, so you have to make a decision in for cases like the hospital named after someone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are heading to Stanford NLP and BIO format. But in case you'd also consider other options, you may have a look a structured entities such as: http://www.afcp-parole.org/etape/docs/etape-06022012-quaero-en.pdf.

Those allow to describe entities as trees, providing a finer analysis for information extraction. More tedious to annotate but probably relevant if you intend to use annotation for semantic purposes, not only indexing.